bcp fails at adding data to table with very simple data file
Please help me understand why the two variants of the bcp command listed below fail at adding data to the DB.
The toy csv-file's (it is in UTF-8 with BOM and has \r\n at the end of each line including the last one) content is as follows:
1,"qwe"
2,"rty"
3,"uio"
4,"äöü"

The test table was created with the command
CREATE TABLE Import_data_test_1([column1][integer], [column2][nvarchar])

Firstly, I tried the bcp command with the following switches:
bcp sn_test_2.dbo.Import_data_test_1 in D:\Uuu\Test_1.csv -w -T -t , -r \n

The result:
Starting copy...
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file

0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1

Also, I attempted to do it interactively like this:
bcp sn_test_2.dbo.Import_data_test_1 in D:\Uuu\Test_1.csv -T

Enter the file storage type of field column1 [int-null]:
Enter prefix-length of field column1 [1]:
Enter field terminator [none]: ,

Enter the file storage type of field column2 [nvarchar]:
Enter prefix-length of field column2 [2]:
Enter field terminator [none]: (comment: I tried left it empty and enter \n here, it did not make any difference)

Do you want to save this format information in a file? [Y/n] n

The result:
Starting copy...

0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1

I would appreciate explanation why it fails in both cases.

Just a note, [column2][nvarchar] it's unwise to skip size for nvarchar

None of those values will fit in your column column2; they are 4 characters too large.

@ThomA I recreated the table with CREATE TABLE Import_data_test_1([column1][integer], [column2][nvarchar](20)), but I did not change the overall picture a bit. It still fails.

@testing-for-ya Thank you, now I see what you mean. But, apparently, it is not the only reason for failure (please see my comment above).

As an alternative you can try BULK INSERT statement in SSMS:
SQL
BULK INSERT sn_test_2.dbo.Import_data_test_1
FROM N'D:\Uuu\Test_1.csv'
WITH (
   FORMAT='CSV' -- starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards
   , FIRSTROW = 1
   , FIELDQUOTE = '"'
   , FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
   , ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' -- '0x0A' 
   , CODEPAGE = '65001'
);

-- test
SELECT * FROM sn_test_2.dbo.Import_data_test_1;


And it does work as expected, thank you very much. It is just that I would like to understand what is wrong with the «bcp variant».

Are you getting any error messages with BULK LOAD? Also, you can try one more option for the ROWTERMINATOR. I added it as a comment.

No, I do not get any error messages, your solution works perfectly well. But not the variant where 0x0A is used in stead of \n, this one fails (SQL Error [4879] [S0001]: Bulk load failed due to invalid column value in CSV data file...) . As I said, I am simply curious to know why the bcp solutions does not (I read the bcp utility was around for quite a long time, so it must be very thoroughly tested in all circumstances; given that it comes as a surprise it fails with such simple file, I feel quite sure the fault is mine for I miss some subtlety and I would be glad to know what it is).

Bcp utility is very old. It is a carry-over from Sybase. It has a separate format file to specify different parameters. As you saw, BULK INSERT also has many parameters, but they are in one place, not separate.
